# Find string from a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dictionary

I have a list with several ingredients:

```
List<string> vegList = new List<string>();
```

where there are several strings like: "cherry", "butter", "bread".

My idea was to have a dictionary or something like that having a recipe string, the name of that recipe is returned if it had one or more elements from the list.

I tried to make a dictionary, and array too, but I didn't get what I wanted.
can anyone help?

i tried this but i don't know what to do anymore

```
myString = "receit pineapple cake, cherry, bread ..."
foreach(string item in vegList )
{
    if(item.Contains(myString))
       return item;
}
```

Comment: Please, share your code and expected result. Right now your question is too broad

Comment: How about [`.FirstOrDefault()` from LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)?

Comment: never heard of it by chance, to see if I research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Linq `Any`:

```
List<string> vegList = new List<string>()
{ "cherry", "butter", "bread"};

string recipe = "butterbread";

bool showRecipe = vegList.Any(s => recipe.Contains(s));
```

`ShowRecipe` returns `true`.

**Edit 1:**
The following code searches for recipes in `recipes` list and returns a `matchedRecipes` list with recipes that match the the words from `vegList`.

```
List<string> vegList = new List<string>()
{ "cherry", "butter", "bread"};

List<string> recipes = new List<string>()
{ "steak", "butterbread", "cherrycake"};

List<string> matchedRecipes = recipes.Where(x => vegList.Any(s => x.Contains(s))).ToList();
```

`matchedRecipes` list contains `"butterbread"` and `"cherrycake"`

**Edit 2**: It would also be helpful to ignore case of letters.

```
List<string> vegList = new List<string>()
{ "cherry", "butter", "bread"};

List<string> recipes = new List<string>()
{ "steak", "Butterbread", "Cherrycake"};

List<string> matchedRecipes = recipes.Where(x => vegList
                                     .Any(s => x.ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower())))
                                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If each recipe has a `vegList`, or more specifically, you have a `Recipe` class with a `List<string> vegList` field, and let's say you have a `List<Recipe> recipes` somewhere:

```
var ingredient = "cherry";

var matches = recipes.FindAll(r => r.vegList.contains(ingredient));
```

`matches` will be a `List<Recipe>` with recipes containing "cherry" as an ingredient.

---

With the new scenario as the question was updated, first make sure your string has ingredients separated all by a space (let's not make it harder).

```
myIngredients = myString.split(" ");
```

Then to find the recipes:

```
var matches = recipes.FindAll(r => r.vegList.Any(l => myIngredients.contains(l)));
```

In this case a recipe is selected if its `vegList` contains at least one of the ingredients in `myIngredients`.

Comment: the problem is that the ingredients are on a list, 
would you have to write ingredient by ingredient?